# Using keyword in speech recognition to trigger an event

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, speech-recognition

I have implementet speech to text to my application and I would like to trigger an event when a certain keyword appears. The application is a chat which actually worked with an normal text input via keyboard and on pressing enter it included this text to the chat like this (onkeydown="ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)")...

But now I would like to include my spoken words to this chat by using a keyword like send, or even better after a break.

(I am using chrome webkit)

```html
        </label> -->
<label for="textInput" class="inputOutline">
<div id="textInput" class="input responsive-column" type="text" onkeydown="/*globals CanvasJS */
            ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this)"></div></label>




<button onclick="startConverting();"><i class="fa fa-microphone"></button>
<script type="text/javascript">



 var r = document.getElementById('textInput');
 function startConverting (){

  if('webkitSpeechRecognition' in window){
 var speechRecognizer = new webkitSpeechRecognition();
 speechRecognizer.continuous = true;
 speechRecognizer.interimResults = true;
 speechRecognizer.lang = 'en-IN';
 speechRecognizer.start();

 var finalTranscripts = '';

 speechRecognizer.onresult = function(event){
          var interimTranscripts = '';
          for(var i = event.resultIndex; i < event.results.length; i++){
           var transcript = event.results[i][0].transcript; 
           transcript.replace("\n", "<br>");
           if(event.results[i].isFinal){
            finalTranscripts += transcript;
           }else{
            interimTranscripts += transcript;
           }}
 if(finalTranscripts.includes('?')){
           window.alert('It works');


          }

          r.innerHTML = finalTranscripts + '<span style="color#999' +interimTranscripts + '</span>'; 
 };

 speechRecognizer.onerror = function (event) {

 };



}else {
 r.innerHTML = 'please update google chrome ';
}

 }



</script>
```

I assume that I need to implement something like this... But I have no idea how.

```html
 if(finalTranscripts.includes('send')){
           XXXXXXXX


          }
```

Any kind of help is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: Your assumption is correct, you just need to try a bit harder.

Comment: Do you have a hint for me ?

Comment: I did it now like this ....   if(finalTranscripts.includes('?')){
           ConversationPanel.inputKeyDown(event, this);


          }     ConversationPanel and inputKeyDown is defined in a different .js file... But it still does not work

Comment: It works like this ....  if(finalTranscripts.includes('?')){
           Api.sendRequest(finalTranscripts, this);


          }  But my Watson services do not work with this, what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You have some progress, congratulations. You can edit your question with new details to get answer.